# How can I schedule a server restart from command line on Windows 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, scheduled-task

I would like to schedule a one-time server restart, e.g. to finish installing updates early in the morning. How can I do this from the command line on Windows 2012?

On Windows 2008, I would have used the `at` command,

```
at 2am shutdown -r -f -c "restart"
```

and taken the rest of the afternoon off.

But on Windows 2012, running this command tells me that

```
The AT command has been deprecated. Please use schtasks.exe instead.
```

So the equivalent command with schtasks.exe might be

```
schtasks /create /sc once /tn restart /tr "shutdown - r -f ""restart""" /st 02:00
```

Apart from being very forgettable, this command has another **important downside**: it schedules the task for 2am **today**—not much use unless I'm awake at 1am to run it.

According to the help for schtasks.exe, the `/sd` switch for setting the start date is not applicable with `/sc once`. So even if I wanted to type out tomorrow's date in mm/dd/yyyy format—and I don't—I can't do this.

The only possible solution I've found is [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/20b5a1f8-54e0-4615-9234-70da66be3384), where Kevin Traas suggests creating batch file to create a scheduled task just before midnight that waits for a couple of minutes and then creates another scheduled task to run the command that you actually want to run. Clever, but nowhere near as convenient as `at`.

Comment: @Lijo that link doesn't contain any information about how to schedule a restart.

Comment: This is just total stupidity to replace AT with unusable schtasks. Why they couldn't make both? Jerks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `shutdown` command itself has a delay parameter `/t` that delays a shutdown for a number of seconds up to 10 years.  If you want to schedule a shutdown in 14 hours, say, you might run

```
shutdown /r /t 50400
```

You might also add a reason with the `/d` parameter or a comment with `/c`; run `shutdown /?` for details.

Answer (score 8):

Despite the documentation, the `/SD` parameter seems to be compatible with the `/SC ONCE`.  The task is successfully created to run on the date provided, at the time provided. (Tested on W8 and W7)

Additionally, [the XP documentation for `schtasks.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true) goes so far as to say the `/SD` parameter is required when using `/SC ONCE`, so I imagine there are a fair number of scripts using the combination.

Example:

```
C:\Users\Mitch>schtasks /create /sc once /tn restart /tr "shutdown -r -f ""restart""" /st 23:00 /sd 2013-06-13
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "restart" has successfully been created.

C:\Users\Mitch>
```

If going against the documentation does not sit well with you, consider generating the XML file directly ([schema is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), which is definitely supported and definitely supports a task scheduled to run once on a future date.  An easy way to get the proper file is to create it in the Task Scheduler `mmc` snap in and [use the export command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709661.aspx).

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2013-06-12T21:20:51.004181</Date>
    <Author>FOOBAR\Mitch</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2013-06-13T22:20:29</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>FOOBAR\Mitch</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>Your command here</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Command to import:

```
schtasks /CREATE /TN "Task Name" /XML filename.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `/sd` being supported. That's interesting about the XML import too—although personally I don't care about going against the documentation. So at least this is possible—just much, much more difficult than it used to be with `at`.

Comment: Mildy interesting: `/sd` doesn't work with `/sc once` on Windows Server 2008. It results in `ERROR: Incorrect Start Date.`

Comment: Hmm... I additionally tested Server 2008 SP2 and Server 2008 R2 without issue.  I will note that the date format is based off of your local date/time format, and leading zeroes are required.  In the default EN-us install, this would lead to formatting like `/SD 06/14/2013`.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating [`runat.ps1`](https://gist.github.com/lukesampson/5778559) to replicate some of the simple features of `at`, incorporating the wisdom from Mitch's answer.

The syntax is `runat (time) (command)`, e.g.

```
runat 2am shutdown -r -f -c "restarting the server"
runat 10:15 msg * it`'s 10:15 everyone!
```

If you, too, are nostalgic for the good old days when you didn't have to type...

```
schtasks /create /ru system /rl highest /sc once /tn restart /tr shutdown -r -f -c \"restarting the server\" /st 02:00 /sd 06/15/2013
```

... then you can install it by running this powershell command:

```
iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://gist.github.com/lukesampson/5779205/raw/install.ps1');install runat https://gist.github.com/lukesampson/5778559/raw
```

Or you can manually download `runat.ps1` script [here](https://gist.github.com/lukesampson/5778559/raw).

Comment: +1 That is a very helpful script... this is definitely going in my favorites.

Answer (score 1):

I used this in a script for 2012 R2 and works nicely;
It will create a daily task that restarts the server @ 4:30am

```
schtasks /create /ru system /rl highest /sc DAILY /tn restart /tr "shutdown /r /f /c "Restarting" /st 04:30
```

Please make sure that you run this from a CMD prompt with Administrative privileges.

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Just another powershell script to programatically reboot the computer the next day at specified time

```
$tomorrowDate = (get-date).AddDays(1).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")

schtasks /delete /tn restart /f
schtasks /create /sc once /ru MyDomain\administrator /rp /tn restart /tr "shutdown -r -f" /st 07:13 /sd $tomorrowDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the schtasks command with the /f parameter.

Using /f, if there is a task with the same name, it's modified.

It's very useful for deploy tasks via scripting.

A full example of a schedule server restart:

```
schtasks /create /ru system /rl highest /sc DAILY /tn Reinicio /tr "shutdown /r /f /t 0 /c "Reinicio"" /st 22:30 /F
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/09/windows-programar-apagado-o-reinicio-automatico.html

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is simply to reboot after installing updates, then you can use the PSWindowsUpdate module to install the updates.  You can download it from [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc). Once installed, just open Powershell and type

```
Get-WuInstall -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
```

Answer (score 0):

This  script lets you schedule the Restart of multiple servers at a specific date / time.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Schedule-restart-of-2c1131fb?redir=0